# what is a single word for a quest or journey of self discovery

Tags: single-word-requests

i need assistance with finding a single word to describe a quest (non religious) for self discovery. i have already tried looking in a thesaurus, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a single word, but ***vision quest*** seems apropos:

> A traditional Native American vision quest consists of a person spending one to four days and nights secluded in nature. This provides time for deep communion with the fundamental forces and spiritual energies of creation and self-identity. During this time of intense spiritual communication a person can receive profound insight into themselves and the world. This insight, typically in the form of a dream of Vision, relates directly to their purpose and destiny in life.<sub><sup>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vision_quest)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

Reflection. Meditation. Contemplate...

Of course, you could *cheat* by hyphenating two words. You ought to consider your own context but this is a vexing quest for such specific word. Good luck!